# Privacy solution for Browser-Sync

Tags: security, browser, sync, privacy

I want to sync my browser bookmarks all over my devices. Now Im thinking about security/privacy topics. There are a lot of articles out there which explains which browser using which method to sync your stuff. Mostly they are using an account from google (chrome) or firefox to identify yourself - sure.

This is a critical point since I'm wondering if the companies are still able to read my data (like having a master PW). Maybe their are well known decentralized solution out there like using a different server.

Maybe you would recommend to dont even use sync-services and instead using something like a custom start-page which holds my links for example.

**EDIT**
My Question is: Is is my synchronized data secure (or can it be encrypted by government or mozilla) and is it possible to use other sync-providers (like hosting my own)

Comment: I'm sorry to ask, but what **is** the question :s ? Your post is written down like a diary entry about your thoughts

Comment: You are right, Ive edited now

Comment: as you told you want to synchronize bookmarks, why do you thinks those are confidential? How do you want to synchronize your customized web page if not through Google or similar?

Comment: The idea of hosting a webpage holding all my bookmarks  was a idea to quit syncing services in the classic way. So everytime I need a bookmark, I have to route to mysuperprivatewebpage.org and using the links on it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that will help:

[mozzila help forums](https://support.mozilla.org/pl/questions/1030282#answer-651609)
If someone will intercept your login and pass to mozilla you are done;

If you want to sync settings (passwords), write a batch and periodically sync firefox .db file though Your eg. sFTP server; if You are sending data to Mozilla's servers consider it as plain text stored passwords